# Setting simplification rules for maple

Tags: maple, simplify

I want to define a rule for a symbol, say "a", such as: $a^3=b*a^2+c*a+d$ and force maple to symplify all my expressions containing $a$ to an expression containing powers of $a$ only up to the square. I have tried "applyrule" but even for $a^4$ maple seems not able to do it. Is there a way to force such simplification rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using *simplification with side-relations*, which means using the `simplify` command with the rule appearing in a particular form of optional argument.

For example,

```
restart;

rule:=a^3=b*a^2+c*a+d:

simplify(a^2, {rule});

                                           2
                                          a

simplify(a^3, {rule});

                                     2
                                    a  b + a c + d

simplify(a^4, {rule});

                              2       2
                            (b  + c) a  + (b c + d) a + b d
```

We can demonstrate the correctness of the previous result using `algsubs`. Note that `algsubs` may be applied more than once, to accomplish that.

```
algsubs(rule, a^4);

                                    3      2
                                   a  b + a  c + a d

algsubs(rule, %);

                              2       2
                            (b  + c) a  + (b c + d) a + b d

ans1 := simplify(a^7, {rule}):

ans2 := algsubs(rule, algsubs(rule, algsubs(rule, algsubs(rule, a^7)))):

normal(ans1 - ans2);

                                           0
```

Note that the simplification with side-relations can also work for expressions which are not just polynomials (in which case it would be even harder to utilize `algsubs` to get the same effect).

```
expr := sin(a^4) + a^3 + sqrt(a^7);

                                         4     3     7 1/2
                            expr := sin(a ) + a  + (a )

simplify(expr, {rule}):

lprint(%);

               b*a^2+c*a+d+sin((b^2+c)*a^2+(b*c+d)*a+b*d)+
               ((b^5+4*b^3*c+3*b^2*d+3*b*c^2+2*c*d)*a^2+
               (b^4*c+b^3*d+3*b^2*c^2+4*b*c*d+c^3+d^2)*
               a+d*(b^4+3*b^2*c+2*b*d+c^2))^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
simplify(a^4, {a^3 = b*a^2+c*a+d});
```

This is called "**simplify** with side relations." The curly braces around the second argument are essential.